# Can I add a short piece of plain text using an 'insert custom CSS' feature of a 3rd party software?

Tags: css

I'd like to add a short piece of plain text to our third party booking platform.  The platform allows me to insert custom CSS through their dashboard. I have no other access to the code.

I would like to put the text in this id: .cf-param-price #cf-param-price_shuttle

.cf-param-price is currently set to display:none; in the Custom CSS.

Is it possible to add text to this id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add text with `:before` or `:after`

like this:

```
.cf-param-price_shuttle:before {
   content: "String Text!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to make it work!

I edited my class block to be more specific in `display:none` and was able to use the`::after content:` in the specified id.

Everything now appears as desired.